# Is it possible to call an awaitable method in a non async method?

Tags: c#, windows-8, async-await

In a windows 8 application in C#/XAML, I sometimes want to call an awaitable method from a non asynchronous method.

Actually is it correct to replace this :

```
  public async Task<string> MyCallingMethod()
  {
      string result = await myMethodAsync();
      return result;
  }
```

by this :

```
   public string MyCallingMethod()
   {
       Task.Run(async () => {
            string result = await myMethodAsync();
            return result;
             });
   }
```

The advantage for me is that I can use MyCallingMethod without await but is this correct?
This can be an advantage if I want to pass a ref parameter for MyCallingMethod since It is not possible to have ref parameters in an async method.

Comment: not gonna work. your anonymous async function will not return value to outer function.

Answer (score 65):

In non-async method you can either start the Task asynchronously and not wait for the result:

```cs
public void MyCallingMethod()
{
    Task t = myMethodAsync();
}
```

or you can attach ContinueWith event handler, which is called after finishing the Task,

```cs
public void MyCallingMethod()
{
    myMethodAsync().ContinueWith(
        result =>
        {
            // do stuff with the result
        });
}
```

or you can get the result from the Task synchronously:

```cs
public string MyCallingMethod()
{
    string result = myMethodAsync().Result;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 26):

You really shouldn't try to do something like that if you're on the UI thread, because that will mean you will block the thread. You should instead work around the `ref` parameter, for example by accepting a parameter of a simple class type, that contains the value you want to change.

Another reason why not to do this is that it still won't let you use `ref` parameters, because lambdas can't access `ref` parameters of the enclosing method.

But if you really want to do this (again, I really think you shouldn't), then you will need to get the result of the `Task`. Something like:

```
public string MyCallingMethod()
{
    var task = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        return await myMethodAsync();
    });
    return task.Result;
}
```

Comment: Nice, self-resolved task and return the result.  Thanks

Comment: Does this avoid the deadlock that would occur by having the main thread block on .Result or Wait()? What's the difference between what you have and calling `var res = myMethodAsync().Result`