# Send email async using SendMailAsync in non Async methods in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, smtpclient

I've been looking at usage of SendMailAsync to get Async emails in my ASP.NET MVC C# website in non-async methods, but I'm unclear whether this actually sends async when inside a non-async method  ... or if there's a way to send it Async in a non-async method and have it work at scale if you're frequently sending emails.

```
smtpclient.SendMailAsync(message);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402681/is-it-possible-to-call-an-awaitable-method-in-a-non-async-method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call asynchronous method from synchronous method in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c)

Comment: Don't do this, it can lead to all kinds of problems. Instead, make the calling function async also.